# Deprecated KStreams TransformerSupplier to ProcessorSupplier

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given that [flatTransform](https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatTransform(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier,java.lang.String...)) is deprecated, I'm trying to replace it by [process](https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...)) as suggested.

My previous *TransformerSupplier* looked like this:

```
public class MyTransformerSupplier implements TransformerSupplier<A, B, Iterable<C, D>> {

  @Override
  public Transformer<A, B, Iterable<C, D>> get() {
    return new MyTransformer();
  }

  @Override
  public Set<StoreBuilder<?>> stores() {
    // Declare a state store
    return Set.of(someStore);
  }
}
```

My actual *ProcessorSupplier* looks like this:

```
public class MyProcessorSupplier implements ProcessorSupplier<A, B, C, D> {

  @Override
  public Processor<A, B, C, D> get() {
    return new MyProcessor();
  }

  @Override
  public Set<StoreBuilder<?>> stores() {
    // Unmodified declaration of the state store
    return Set.of(someStore);
  }
}
```

And the only significant difference between my previous [Transformer](https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html) and my new [ContextualProcessor](https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/ContextualProcessor.html) is that instead of returning a List, several calls to `context().forward(...)` are executed internally.

The error is precisely that `context()` is null for my new *ContextualProcessor*.
**Could you help me understand why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override method `init()`, there you can initialize a variable context that will be supplied automatically by Kafka streams.

In Scala, you can do something like this

```scala
private var context: ProcessorContext = _ 

override def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
   this.context = context 
}
```

You then use that variable to forward records.